# American C# developer looking to move to EU

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, career

I am a C# developer and a US citizen. I wanted to explore software development or engineering roles in start ups in EU, in particular in cities such as Amsterdam, London or Stockholm. I have a master in electrical engineering with a few years of hands on circuit design under my belt, but I have been doing enterprise software development for a few years as well. How does it work? how can I find serious job interviews in EU?

Comment: Do you have any preferences on where in the EU you go (it's a big and diverse place!), or would you mostly be influenced by where you'd find someone to sponsor you for a work visa?

Comment: I'm more interested in Western or Northern Europe for now.

Comment: @BostonMan That's still a lot of countries.

Comment: @Karlson How about UK or the Netherlands?

Comment: @BostonMan it's like you're asking for a job in western or Northern US. Do you prefer LA, SF, Seattle, Boulder…?

Comment: Ok, Amsterdam or London are my primary preferences. Then may be Stockholm in Sweden.

Comment: Welcome to Expats! This is really broad - if you had a particular question that was narrowed down to one country, and the question surrounded quirks in finding employment as a non-citizen (presumably, with your intention to move there), then it would probably be on-topic.

Comment: @TimPost I narrowed down the question, please lift the hold.

Comment: Note that as a US citizen looking for work and a long-stay (i.e. not a short touristic visit), your situation will depend on the local law and there might be a lot of differences between countries regarding the requirements to get a visa, even within the EU.

Answer (score 5):

well, basically, you search tech jobs using the same sites worldwide. You may want to attend startup meet ups in cities you're targetting, but you can find them on the same meetup sites as in the US. Otherwise, you may want to have a look at:

- http://angel.co if you really want a startup experience ;
- http://jobs.stackoverflow.com if you want a bigger corp experience (usually startup are less keen to pay the careers 2.0 fee) ;
- http://linkedin.com and http://viadeo.com are also widely used in EU.

There are european categories for all the other sites as well e.g.: [indeed france](http://www.indeed.fr) exception made of dice.com…

In the countries I know, i.e. France, UK and Germany, usually the recruitment process is having you go for a couple of interviews (or one if you can go on-site), and make you do some basic tech questions but more importantly look at whether your profile is a fit or not for the firm. If things work out, they take you on a double 3 month probatory period before having you definitely hired.

Then the contract and legal aspects themselves will differ from country to country.

Edit:

as a general advice, you should not target wide areas, such as countries, or blurry areas such as "western europe", but more target cities so you can create filters in the search engines:

- UK: London, Nottingham
- Netherlands: Amsterdam, Den Haag, Rotterdam
- France: Paris, Lyon, Nantes
- Germany: Berlin, Frankfurt, Hamburg, Köln

Comment: Yea this is even relative to me and i am in the UK looking for contract work.